# Matching two paths in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to match a path to a stream of path can anybody help

Here is the initial code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/Users/UCD/eclipse-workspace/metrics_cal/src/test/resources/xerces2-j-Xerces-J_2_8_0"))) 
    {
         Path path1 = Paths.get("\"C:/Users/UCD/eclipse-workspace/metrics_cal/src/test/resources/xerces2-j-Xerces-J_2_8_0/xerces2-j-Xerces-J_2_8_0/src/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/SAXParserImpl.java\";");

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

paths have collection of all the paths of a folder and path1 is the one I want to match with but problem is paths is a stream and path1 is not how can I do it?

Comment: Stream is a powerfull API in java. You can use anyMatch or filter method on Stream to match with path1. bool match = paths.anyMatch(w -> w.equals(path1))
https://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-stream-allmatch-anymatch-nonematch-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Stream.anyMatch()`:

```
String directory = "C:/Users/UCD/eclipse-workspace/metrics_cal/src/test/resources/xerces2-j-Xerces-J_2_8_0";
String file = "\"C:/Users/UCD/eclipse-workspace/metrics_cal/src/test/resources/xerces2-j-Xerces-J_2_8_0/xerces2-j-Xerces-J_2_8_0/src/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/SAXParserImpl.java\";";
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(directory))) {
    Path path1 = Paths.get(file);
    if(paths.anyMatch(path1::equals)){
        // do something
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```